# Python Pandas save to csv Column headers garbled

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a web scraper and i have 3 lists containing items, and i am trying to save them to a csv file and i want associate each list of items to a column header like *name list* goes under column **NAME** *email list* go under column **EMAIL** and so on, but for some reason everything is getting grouped together in one column

**here is the code**

```
foundings = {'NAME': namelist, 'EMAIL': emaillist, 'PHONE': phoneliist}
Save_to_Csv(foundings)

    def Save_to_Csv(data):
        filename = 'loki.csv'

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)

        df.set_index('NAME', drop=True, inplace=True)

        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            with open(filename,'a') as f:
                df.to_csv(f, mode='a', sep="\t", header=False, encoding='utf-8')
        else:
            df.to_csv(filename, sep="\t")
```

simple enough code to make the **NAME** the index and add each list of elements to associated columns

but it does something like this
[image]

***Groups everything together in a single column***

what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: You wrote out a tab separated file, is your viewer correctly parsing these tabs? It maybe expecting commas as separators unsurprisingly

Comment: libreoffice works fine .. for pandas and data frames like these but for some reason this is not working

Comment: sorry it was a libreoffice fault ... i opened with google spreadsheets and it works fine sorry i am deleting the question